# laravel 7 'laravel.password_resets' doesn't exist

Tags: php, laravel, api, passwords

I am trying to send email to user for forget password using rest API,
here is my controller:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gV0QU.png)

strong text
put when I call this forget function by my Api on postman it gives this error :
'laravel.password_resets' doesn't exist
how can I solve this issue

Comment: Please check do you have password_resets table in your DB?

Answer (score 1):

Please run

php artisan migrate

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility that your would have dropped the database table.

```
Php artisan migrate: fresh
```